# Não consigo colocar uma nova coluna dentro de uma tabela

Tags: php, html, css

Gostava que me pudessem ajudar a colocar uma coluna (pintado a amarelo) da seguinte forma que se encontra na imagem anexada. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deixo aqui também o meu código de momento para poder dar uma ajuda:

```
<?php
    $database ="anomalias";
    $server="127.0.0.1";

    $connect= mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $selecionar= mysql_select_db('anomalias');
    if ($selecionar) 
        {
            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM laboratorios";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

            echo"<br>";                
            echo "<table border='1'>";            
            echo "<td style='padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px'><h6>Salas</h6></td>";


            while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
            {       
                echo "<td style='padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px'> <a href='phpeditarsala.php?id=".$db_field['sala']."'>".$db_field['sala']."</a></td>";

            }

            echo "</table>";
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Você quer colocar 8 colunas na tabela, porém sua query só retorna 7 registros, resultando apenas em 7 colunas ?

Comment: Por exemplo, eu sempre que adiciono um campo na bd eu gostava que aparece-se o campo inserido e também uma coluna em baixo onde depois existisse um botão para poder editar!

Comment: Quantas colunas tem a tabela no banco de dados ?

Comment: Actualmente só tem uma que é a que exibe as salas, e eu queria que debaixo dela   (linha)   aparece-se uma outra que exibisse um botão para editar os dados

Comment: Você quer o botão embaixo, então ok.

Comment: Sim quero que apareça sempre outro botão se aparecer uma outra sala, para depois esse botão levar o id e poder editar as mesmas

Comment: Ok, vou postar sua solução.

Comment: Pronto, verifica se é isso que você quer.

Comment: O mal é que da maneira que meteu os dados são mostrados em coluna e não em linha e assim caso exista 1000 dados na bd a pagina da web tera um scroll infinito

Comment: Por isso eu me referi a estética, com relação a quantidade de resultados, para evitar scroll muito grande, você pode paginar os resultados.

Comment: Ja tentei paginar num outro trabalho e não consegui... ainda sou aprendiz de javascript

Comment: Mas obrigado, já consegui arranjar uma maneira com a sua ajuda.

Comment: Posso te ajudar a criar o recurso de paginação, pode me mandar um email.
Já que resolveu, me da o +1 e coloca como melhor solução, por favor, obrigado.

Comment: Que feio isso, cadê as TRs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está fantando a tag `<tr></tr>` que designa as linhas.

Esteticamente está feio, você pode melhorar isso adicionando mais um campo nessa tabela onde vai colocar um botão na mesma linha onde imprimi seu resultado.

```
<?php
    $database ="anomalias";
    $server="127.0.0.1";

    $connect= mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $selecionar= mysql_select_db('anomalias');
    if ($selecionar) 
        {
            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM laboratorios";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

            echo"<br>";                
            echo "<table border='1'>";            



            while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
            {       
                echo "<tr><td style='padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px'><h6>Salas</h6></td>";
                echo "<td style='padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px'> <a href='phpeditarsala.php?id=".$db_field['sala']."'>".$db_field['sala']."</a></td></tr>";

            }

            echo "</table>";
        }

    ?>
```

Acredito que é isso.